# Array.isArray is deprecated now?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I'm coding TypeScript on WebStorm IDE.
The IDE tells that the method *Array.isArray* is deprecated (like in the image), and I doubt it. Also, I couldn't find information about it

```js
let items: any[] = Array.isArray(jsonData.items) ? jsonData.items : [];
```

[image]

is Array.isArray really deprecated? Thanks

Comment: For anyone else who happens upon this, I found that my code was using isArray from 'util' and changing that from `isArray()` to `Array.isArray()` addressed the concern.

Comment: To anyone that is using `Array.isArray()` and getting this error I found adding `ES6` (or above) in the tsconfig > compilerOptions > lib array also fixes this.

Answer (score 5):

[Array.isArray appears in the latest draft specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.isarray) where it is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: Please explain how to avoid warning in WebStorm.  The comment by apokryfos on OPs question attempts to do this, but answer there is incomplete or mangled (I guess it's due to limit in comment formatting).